# python generate Posix time from time of day

Tags: python

Given a time string I need to create a unixtime value. I can do it like this but it seems way overcomplicated.

```
def tounix(timestr):
    from datetime import date, datetime
    from time import mktime
    return mktime(datetime.combine(date.today(),datetime.strptime(timestr,'%H%M%S').time()).timetuple())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print tounix(sys.argv[1])
```

My experience so far in python is that there is always a MUCH simpler way of doing things than the one I find. Anyone got any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks pretty close to what I'd write. I'd just use the time module though.

```
from time import *

# make a time string
t = strftime('%H%M%S', localtime())

# convert time string to unix time (seconds since epoch)
mktime(localtime()[:3] + strptime(t, '%H%M%S')[3:])
```

Comment: That's much better. Thanks.